# My Virtual Server Linux Dosen't connect to internet

Tags: linux, server, dns, virtualhost

I Have Virtual server That My App is connected this and webService is on there
app can connect and get data and i can connect to that by vnc-Viewer or ...
but
server can not connect to internet or any website
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two option for VM.
1. linux
2. window.

1. Linux :- check and find the ip has connected to ethernet port and also entry to /etc/resolv.conf. 
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4

then start the network service using command service network restart(centos-6) and also start sshd service for outside ping.

2. Window:-  in window case you have to check  that remote setting has enabled.

   ### window property - > remote setting.

then ping the ip outside the network, it may be work